# Is it correct to write a Class just to render a single form element?

Tags: php, oop

So my boss and I couldn't reach an agreement about how it's best to render form elements. Our form looks like this:

```
<form class='myform'>
    <input type=text class="username" />
    <span><img class="question-mark-icon" src='icon.png' /></span>
    <div class="tooltip"><p>Your username.</p></div>

    // Other form elements here
</form>
```

We have three forms that have one or two the same elements. Right now they are rendered via a helper function so if I call `username()` it would render that element along with its tooltip. So in actuality one of our forms looks like this:

```
<form class='myform'>
     <?php username(); ?>

     // Other form elements here
</form>
```

I think it works okay and that's how it's done in Wordpress and other codes I've read so I assumed that's the best practice. But he argues that we should make it object oriented as in OOP like this:

```
class FormElements {
    public function username() {
       echo '<input type=text class="username" /><span><img class="question-mark-icon" src='icon.png' /></span>
       <div class="tooltip"><p>Your username.</p></div>';
    }
}
```

So obviously to render the `username` input would be like so:

```
$formEls = new FormElements();
$formEls->username();
```

So could anyone tell us clearly why it's better/worse to do it that way as opposed to placing it in a helper function like this:

```
function username() {
    echo '<input type=text class="username" /><span><img class="question-mark-icon" src='icon.png' /></span>
        <div class="tooltip"><p>Your username.</p></div>';
}
```

My argument is that it's silly to create a class just to render a single element when you can do it using a simple helper function? Also it doesn't do any justice to OOP principles. But he wouldn't believe me and asked to me to point him to an authority article or anything with authority that would back my claim/understanding.

*EDIT:*

Could you also tell why it's okay to place it in a Class? I couldn't define a proper Object model for it. I usually create Class for objects with clear properties and actions. For a single form element, I don't see why I should wrap it in a Class.

Comment: The really good idea here would be to stop using `echo` in those functions. PS: the "proper" OO solution would introduce `UsernameFormElement` class that `implements IRenderable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class will have only one method, you can use a helper instead of creating a class for that. Unless you think you will add new features to it in the future. In that case I would try to separate it in these parts...

For example you could split it in:

1) a Form.class.php file which could contain each form field. 
It could be something like this...
ie:

```
class Form {
  private $fields = array();
  private $method;
  private $action;

  public _construct( $action, $method, $arrayWithFieldsData){ //here you should populate with FormField instances the private $fields array, and set the method and action attributes };
  public toHtml() { 
    //here you should RETURN a string 
    $output = '<form action="'.$this->action.'" method="'.$this->method.'" />';
    foreach($this->fields as $f){
      $output .= $f->toHtml();
    }
    return $output.' </form>';
  };
  public validate() { //here you could implement form validation };
}
```

2) an AbstractFormField.class.php or a FormFieldInterface.php which could have a getHtml() signature

```
abstract class AbstractFormField {

    public function _construct($arrayOfHtmlAttrs){
      $this->htmlAttr = $arrayOfHtmlAttrs;
    }

    public function toHtml();
}
```

3) a class for each FormField, that would extend AbstractFormField or implement FormFieldInterface.
ie: InputFormField.class.php, HiddenFormField.class.php, SelectFormField.class.php.

```
class InputFormField extends AbstractFormField {

    public method toHtml(){
      $out = '<input type="text" ';
      foreach ($this->htmlAttr as $key => $value){
        $out .= " $key = $value ";
      }
      $out .= " />
      return $out;
    }
}
```

4) This code could go on your html, although it will be better to isolate it on a controller:

```
<?php 
  $fields = array(
              'username' => array( 'text', array('value' => $username, 'class' => 'username-input', 'id' => "some-id-for-your-fields)),
              'password' => array( 'password', array('value' => $username, 'class' => 'username-pswd', 'id' => "some-id-for-your-field)),
  );
  $myForm = new Form($action, $method, $fields);
?>
```

5) And this on your html:

```
  <?php echo $myForm->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to define them as static functions:

```
class FormElements {
    public static function username() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Later:

```
<?php FormElements::username() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside **how** to write the class, is the point of scalability.

Consider this: Later on you realize, that you also need to add a `fullName` element to the form. With your approach you would add a new function called `fullName()`. So far so good, but what if you need more and more. You would have lots of functions. If you then need to have similar functions for an email for example things will get messy and you do not know exactly what function is now meant to be for.
With classes this gets easier to maintain and extend. You would only do this `FormElement::username()` and `EMailElement::username()`, etc.

(Ignore if it is a good idea to do it exactly this way.)

See how much easier things are getting?

We can push this even further and can add a  `User` class like this:

```
class User {

    protected $infos = array();

    public function __construct($infos = array()) {
        $this->infos = $infos;
    }
}
```

Now you Element classes can extend the user class and get all infos like the username for example from one place.

Of course you have to follow this kinda order:

```
$user = new User(array("username" => "Bob"));
$form_element = new FormElement($user);
```

Your `Element` class could then look something like this:

```
abstract class Element extends User {
    protected function getStyle($element);
    protected function getTag($element);
    // etc .. Add implementation as well!!
}
```

Of course you could add a `Element` class which will get extended by `Form` and `Email`, add interfaces, etc.

But to use the OOP approach seems better here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps. I have implemented in the past a Form generator that works on top of CodeIgniter php framework, and it allows to define dynamic forms; you can define field by field, or you can build a form from a Doctrine ORM model definition in one line. It also can be extended to work with other ORMs.
Maybe it is off help to give you ideas about how to implement yours.
I am not maintaining it any more.
Of course: feel free to use it if you see it fits your needs.

I have implemented more than two years ago and I used it in a production project for about one year. That gave me the opportunity to iterate over it and improve it gradually. Later I have packet it inside one commit and pushed it to Github. Is not a state of the art.

Today I would do it differently, For example, I would take more advantage of magic methods to simplify the code and make it more flexible (like the FormField class for example which looks too Java in my opinion).

Here is the code:

https://github.com/theconejou/form_generator

here are the core classes.

https://github.com/theconejou/form_generator/tree/master/forms/base

PS: Mmmm... I am reading the code after a looong time and definitively I would do it different today: too large methods in some classes, too less simplicity, too Java for php... Anyway...